# Intent for opening external camera app

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

Is there possibility just to **open external camera** application and **let it take picture, save it and notify media_scanner** for me? I'm googling for a long time now and everything I found are just topics about calling camera intent and need to process taken image myself.

I don't want to have need for WRITE_STORAGE and CAMERA permissions in my app, I just want to access gallery and direct user to external camera if needed.

PS In case anyone wants to **downwote** this question, please, **explain yourself** after read it one more time carefully. Thanks!

Comment: "need to process taken image myself" -- what "process" are you referring to? `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` will save the image for you if you supply `EXTRA_OUTPUT` (and the camera app doesn't have bugs), and you do not need any permissions to use `MediaScannerConnection` and `scanFile()` to notify the media scanner.

Comment: sry, was afk. Sure, I'm passing Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM) -> Uri as an EXTRA_OUTPUT parameter. The file is physically there if I check it but it looks like no media_scanner is called - picture does not appear in standard gallery nor in my MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI loader. Should I force scanner manually in my onActivityResult()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in my comment, `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` will save the image for you if you supply `EXTRA_OUTPUT` (and the camera app doesn't have bugs), and you do not need any permissions to use `MediaScannerConnection` and `scanFile()` to notify the media scanner. There is no requirement, as part of `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` processing, for the camera app to arrange for your file to be indexed, in part because the camera app does not know if that is what you want.

> Sure, I'm passing Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM) -> Uri as an EXTRA_OUTPUT parameter

That will not work reliably. `EXTRA_OUTPUT` needs to point to a file to be written to, not a directory. If you provide a directory, [I would expect behavior to be rather variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31678146/saving-image-taken-from-camera-into-internal-storage/31679200#31679200).

> Should I force scanner manually in my onActivityResult()?

That seems like a fine plan.

Comment: Sure, that's a directory, I'm creating file inside like it's mentioned in Google docs  here http://goo.gl/BCkWmN

Comment: OK, calling sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, uri)); in onActivityResult() helped, thanks for kicking me on the right way.